# What is faster in MySQL? WHERE sub request = 0 or IN list

Tags: mysql, sql, database, pdo

I was wondering what is better in MySQL. I have a SELECT query that exclude every entry associated to a banned userID.

Currently I have a subquery clause in the WHERE statement that goes like

```
AND (SELECT COUNT(*) 
     FROM TheBlackListTable 
     WHERE userID = userList.ID 
       AND blackListedID = :userID2 ) = 0
```

Which will accept every `userID` not present in the `TheBlackListTable`

Would it be faster to retrieve first all Banned ID in a previous request and replace the previous clause by

```
AND creatorID NOT IN listOfBannedID
```

Comment: What about BENCHMARK or EXPLAIN EXTENDED?

Answer (score 2):

`LEFT JOIN / IS NULL` and `NOT IN` are fastest:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    mytable
WHERE   id NOT IN
        (
        SELECT  userId
        FROM    blacklist
        WHERE   blackListedID = :userID2
        )
```

or

```
SELECT  m.*
FROM    mytable m
LEFT JOIN
        blacklist b
ON      b.userId = m.id
        AND b.blackListedID = :userID2
WHERE   b.userId IS NULL
```

`NOT EXISTS` yields the same plan but due to implementation flaws is marginally less efficient:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    mytable
WHERE   NOT EXISTS
        (
        SELECT  NULL
        FROM    blacklist b
        WHERE   b.userId = m.id
                AND b.blacklistedId = :userID2
        )
```

All these queries stop on the first match in `blacklist` (hence performing a `semi-join`)

The `COUNT(*)` solution is the least efficient, since `MySQL` will calculate the actual `COUNT(*)` rather than stopping on the first match.

However, if you have a `UNIQUE` index on `(userId, blacklistedId)`, this is not much of  problem as there cannot be more than one match anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Use `EXISTS` clause to check for user not in blacklist.

Sample Query

```
Select * from userList
where not exists( Select 1 from TheBlackListTable  where userID = userList.ID)
```

`IN` clause is used when there is fixed values or low count of values.